# Stochastic Automaton accepting every word with same probability

Tags: probability, formal-languages, automata

I am looking for a stochastic automaton, which induces the same probability $c \in [0,1]$ for all words in $\Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma$ is some finite alphabet.

A stochastic automaton over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a tuple $\mathcal A$= { $\mathcal Q$, $\Sigma$, $\pi$, $(P_a)_{a\in \Sigma}$, $\mathcal f$} where

- $\mathcal Q = \{1,2,...,n\}$ is a finite set of states
- $\pi \in [0,1]$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i = 1 $ (inital probability distribution)
- for each $a \in \Sigma$, $P_a$ is a $n \times n$ transition matrix taking values in $[0,1]$ such that for all row $i = 1,...,n$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n (P_a)_{ij} = 1 $
- $f \in [0,1]^{n \times 1}$ is the final state vector such that $f(i) = 1$ iff state $i$ is final.

If $\pi = (p_1,..., p_n)$ is the initital distribution, the probability to reach state $j$ by reading a word $w = a_1 ... a_n $ $\in \Sigma$ is given by $(\pi \cdot P_w )_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i \cdot (P_w)_{ij}$

If the automaton $\mathcal A$ has $f = (f_1,..., f_n) $ as a final vector, it is then in a final state with the probability $\sum_{i=1}^n (\pi_i \cdot P_w)_{j} \cdot f_i = \pi \cdot P_w \cdot f$.

Example: $w = aab$ $\Rightarrow $ $\pi \cdot P_w \cdot f = \pi \cdot P_a² \cdot P_b \cdot f$

I constructed the following automaton so that every word has the same probability.

$\mathcal Q = \{1\}$, $\pi = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$ , $f =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$, $P_\epsilon =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$and $P_\Sigma =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$.

Then $\pi \cdot P_{\Sigma^*}^n \cdot f = 1 = c $ But in this case $c = 1$ and not arbitrary.

My observations:

- $2$ states are necessary since
- the probability c has to be split in $1-c$ and c for $a \in \Sigma$
  transitions
- there are different options to involve c: In $\pi$, $P_\Sigma*$ and/or in $f$

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: The set $\Sigma^*$ is infinite hence there is no uniform distribution on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the $2\times 2$  identity, $\pi=(c,1-c)$, $f=(1,0)$. Then all words have the same probability $c$ of being accepted.

Comment: I am wondering if that is a feasible automaton? When state 2 is assigned to be the inital state by a probability of 1-c then we will never end up in the accepting state 1 since there are no transitions.

Comment: Which is exactly what you want since you want to avoid a probability higher then $c$.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thanks to everyone!